# Is it possible to fine-tune access control in Hyperledger Fabric private data collections further than restricting entire organizations?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, access-control, privacy

In the [Hyperledger Fabric Docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data-arch.html#private-data-collection-definition), while reading about private data collections I came accross this sentence regarding memberReadOnly:

> Utilize a value of false if you would like to encode more granular access control within individual chaincode functions.

If I understand this correctly, this allows me to code into the smart contract specifications that will allow me to limit control to eg. specific clients of one organization instead of all peers of member organizations.

If that is so, I am curious as to how this can be done in the contract. Is there a specific way to handle access control or is it at my own discretion to write code that will enforce it? If you can provide me with any examples it would be very helpful.

To clarify what I mean, I come from Ethereum and what I am essentially asking is whether there is something like the require method in solidity, or would I just use a simple if.

Thanks for any help. If you close question for wrong site, please point me to the right place as I have not been able to find somewhere more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't understand correctly.

Setting this value (`memberOnlyRead`) to `true` means that if a client sends a proposal to a peer, and the client is not in the collection, then if the peer is in the collection and has access to the data - it will refuse with an error automatically no matter the smart contract says.

If it's false, then the peer won't enforce such a thing, and then you have more freedom to code any access control logic you want for the clients.